# Thinkpad dual-monitor connectivity issue in a docking station

Tags: multi-monitor, thinkpad, amd-graphics, displayport, dock-station

- Laptop is `ThinkPad P14s Gen 1 (AMD)` with dedicated GPU
- Docking station: `40AJ` (port colors don't match the ones in the picture, but should be [this one](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/uu/en/solutions/pd500173))
- Two identical screens are connected via DP
- no desktop environment, [i3](https://i3wm.org/) window manager

---

Issues started right from the start ~2 years ago (~beginning of 2021):

- computer couldn't be suspended, as at resume the screens wouldn't connect
- computer couldn't be detached & re-attached from the docking station for same reason
- if screens where to switch off due to power saving, then more often than not they wouldn't connect properly when they were woken up
- if you'd let screens switch off by power saver and then wait through the endless flickering on wake-up in hopes they'd reconnect, it usually ended up in a crash - likely the gpu drivers

Thus far I've avoided these issues by not suspending, not detaching from docking station, and instead of allowing screens to go to power saving mode, I'd switch them off via the physical pwr button -- for some reason this didn't cause the problems on eventual wake-up.

Past week or two (~beginning of 2023), however, the problems have gotten worse:

- screens hardly connect on startup (didn't use to be an issue)
- if they do connect, then oftentimes the second screen mirrors the first
- the workaround by switching screens off via the pwr button no longer works - screens fail to connect on wake-up.

---

```
$ lspci -k | grep -EA3 'VGA'
07:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Renoir (rev d1)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Renoir
    Kernel driver in use: amdgpu
    Kernel modules: amdgpu
```

```
$ uname -a
Linux p14s 6.1.0-1-amd64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Debian 6.1.4-1 (2023-01-07) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Unsure what data to provide, but [here are some possibly relevant stack traces from kern log](https://gist.github.com/laur89/20eea036016c3c1520cc4f95489fd9ff)

---

Edit: Looks like it's reverted back to the old state of things - I can sort of get around it by not suspending/detaching from dock, but after long idle the monitors still won't reconnect.

**Edit 2** June '23: after updating to `trixie` (codename of new Debian testing/next stable), the problem appears to have disappeared altogether. Current likely related packages:

```
firmware-amd-graphics      20230515-2
xserver-xorg-video-radeon  1:19.1.0-3
xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu  23.0.0-1
linux-image-amd64          6.3.7-1
libdrm2                    2.4.115-1
libdrm-amdgpu1             2.4.115-1
```

Comment: Try the BIOS upgrade to version [1.42 (2023/01/03)](https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/downloads/ds544977-bios-update-utility-bootable-cd-for-windows-10-64-bit-thinkpad-t14-gen-1-types-20ud-20ue) and [40AJ firmware update](https://pcsupport.lenovo.com/us/de/products/accessory/docks/thinkpad-ultra-docking-station/40aj/downloads/DS505699?CID=ww%3Alenovosocial%3A20x9m6) first.

Comment: BIOS has been upgraded, but still waiting access for a Windows machine to update the docking station fw.